# Python - Group Data in new Columns based on identical values - Same file

Tags: python

I have a csv file, that has the following:

Name,Number,Value

**A,1**,X

B,0,Y

**C,0**,Z

**A,1**,Y

**A,0**,Z

**C,0**,X

**A,1**,Y

**A,0**,Z

how can I group it and make the output on a new csv file look like this:

Name,Number,Value

A,1,X,Y,Y

B,0,Y

C,0,Z,X

A,0,Z,Z

so I set the condition on the first two columns, if they match, then aggregate the Value.
I tried reading a lot about it, but I cant seem to find the explanation on how to add a condition and re-arrange the data.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have CSV file called **`input.csv`** with the following contents:

```
Name,Number,Value
A,1,X
B,0,Y
C,0,Z
A,1,Y
A,0,Z
C,0,X
A,1,Y
A,0,Z
```

You could use **[pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)** to produce your desired `output.csv`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
new_df = df.groupby(['Name', 'Number'], as_index=False,
                    sort=False).agg({'Value': ','.join})
new_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

**`output.csv` after running above:**

```
Name,Number,Value
A,1,"X,Y,Y"
B,0,Y
C,0,"Z,X"
A,0,"Z,Z"
```

**Documentation Links:**

- [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)

Comment: Thanks Sash, what is the name of this? so I can read more about it?

Comment: @YahyaJaber Added some documentation links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to accumulate rows where the first two columns match. In this case we use a `defaultdict` with a `list` as the value type.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

tmp = defaultdict(list)
with open("foo.csv", "r") as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    for line in reader:
        a,b,val = line
        key = (a, b)
        tmp[key].append(val)

print(tmp)
defaultdict(list,
            {('A', '1'): ['X', 'Y', 'Y'],
             ('B', '0'): ['Y'],
             ('C', '0'): ['Z', 'X'],
             ('A', '0'): ['Z', 'Z']})

with open("outfile.csv", "w") as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for k, v in tmp.items():
        row = list(k) + v
        writer.writerow(row)

"""
A,1,X,Y,Y
B,0,Y
C,0,Z,X
A,0,Z,Z
"""
```